# Constrained polymorphism: variable vs. function parameter

Tags: haskell

This is a very basic question. I have just started studying Haskell using a couple of different sources. There is something I can't currently decipher from these.

The following will naturally typecheck just fine.

```
g :: Num a => a -> a
g x = x + 2
h = g (1.0 :: Double)
```

This example of constrained polymorphism makes complete sense to me when I interpret it as follows: as long as the parameter provided to `g` is of the type that has a `Num` instance, everything is ok.

So, consider the following.

```
x :: Num a => a
```

If I interpret this as above, I get: `x` can take any value of a type that has a `Num` instance. However, the following will *not* typecheck.

```
x :: Num a => a
x = (1.0 :: Double)
```

My question is: what is *exactly* the difference here?

I *sort of* get what *might be* happening: in the second example, `x` is defined so that it will evaluate to any `Num`, and  `(1.0 :: Double)` does not qualify.

But my vague idea is far from being a complete explanation, and I am looking for a better one.

Comment: With `x :: Num a => a` you define an ad-hoc polymorphic type and with `x = (1.0 :: Double)` you immediately "convert" it to a monomorphic type when binding a value of that type to a variable. This doesn't make sense. If you want `x` to be of type `Double`, then define it as such in the first place.

Comment: Another, identical, way to write `x :: Num a => a` is `x :: forall a. Num a => a`.

Comment: `g` does not get to "choose" what type to return; *the caller* gets to choose. The type signature claims that `g` can return any possible number type... but actually it always returns `Double`. So the type signature is lying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the type `g :: Num a => a -> a` as follows:

- the caller of `g` chooses a type `a`
- the caller must prove that `a` is a numeric type
- the caller must provide an argument value of type `a`
- `g` must then answer with a result value of type `a`

Hence, `x :: Num a => a` becomes

- the user of `x` chooses a type `a`
- the user must prove that `a` is a numeric type
- `x` must then answer with a result value of type `a`

So, `x` is not allowed to pick `a = Double`, the user of `x` gets to choose that.
Think e.g. of `(x :: Int) + 4`: this will type check, picking `a=Int`. The implementation of `x` must be general, so to work on all the numeric type.

Incidentally, note that numeric literals have the same type `42 :: Num a => a`, this is why we are allowed to use them as `Double`, as `Int`, or any other numeric type.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and unifies the two cases: the specific type is always selected by the caller. It would even be possible to define `x` so that it would also be a function: `x :: Num a => () -> a` and `x = \ () -> 1`. Thanks!